# How do I get GCE Silver support?

Tags: google-compute-engine

A few days ago I subscribed to GCE Silver support. However, I cannot find anywhere to submit a support ticket. The only place I find is enterprise.google.com/supportcenter but that is only for Google Apps Enterprise and not GCE.

Does anyone know where to submit GCE support ticket requests for GCE? I can't believe how hidden this is for paying customers. Of course I can't call Google to ask where to do this because that requires a $400+ Gold plan.

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3420056?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Andrew, if you have Silver support, you can visit https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter/managecases for the Google Enterprise Support Center. You should be able to login. With Silver you can have up to 2 individuals with log-in access. You can visit https://cloud.google.com/support/ for that information.

Once logged in, you should be able to open a support ticket.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. This is where I have been going. When I select a new case, the drop down offers nothing for GCE that I can see. I try to select the closet option possible but my tickets end up going to Google Enterprise Apps support and then they respond to me saying that they don't support GCE cloud services. When I ask them where should I be going, they point me to the same URL again...what am I missing here? Seems like a catch 22

Comment: When you're logged in and you go to create a case, on the same line the first column should say what kind of service it is. It should be saying 'Cloud Services'. Is that the case for you? or does it say Google Apps?

Comment: it says Google Apps. I don't have anything for Cloud Services

`Product Name Support Start Support End Action
Google Apps   domain.com   10/24/10      12/13/14`

Comment: With that said, what would I need to do to have it also show Cloud Services?

Comment: If you have billing enabled and you're actually paying for the GCE service, you should also have a 'Cloud Services' entry. Take a look in the top left, under the Google logo it should say the account name. If you click on it, you may be able to swap to a different account. If there are any options to swap to a different acc you might get the correct Cloud Services entry there.

Comment: Boyan..you nailed it!!! At the top left hand corner under the Google logo, I had my account and when I hover over it, I get a separate option for "Cloud Services Account". Previously, it was at my domain.com Account so I didn't even think that was an option to hover over it. I just thought the domain.com part was just indicating my account name and not that it was actually an optional account setting link. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so that others may see it. Thanks.